# Set the start point for time intervals in R

Tags: r, time, format

I have different sets of data with the following format

```
Time                    Value1 Value2 ....
11/04/2015  15:12:22    1      2      ....
11/04/2015  15:13:46    1      2      ....
```

And I want to group them in intervals of 15 minutes. I can do this with the following code

```
data$time = cut(data$time, breaks = "15 min")
data.grouped <- aggregate(data[,c(-1)], by = list(time = datos$time), median)
```

The problem is that the time field in the output has the following values

```
12/04/2015 16:12
12/04/2015 16:27
12/04/2015 16:42
12/04/2015 16:57
```

And I want the times to be :00 :15 :30 or :45. Is there any way of forcing the intervals to be like this or a different approach to merge the data that allows it?

A sample data from dput:

```
structure(list(time = structure(list(sec = c(49, 5, 21, 37, 54, 
10, 38), min = c(12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 22L), hour = c(15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L), mday = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 12L), mon = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), year = c(116L, 
116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L), wday = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L), yday = c(101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 102L
), isdst = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), zone = c("CEST", "CEST", 
"CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", 
"year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", "zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt")), value1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("time", 
"value1"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you share sample data with `dput()` so it's easy to copy/paste? The way you show it, it doesn't look like it's actually a datetime class, but the way you use it it must be.... `dput()` will also clear up any confusion on that.

Comment: Maybe you just want `lubridate::floor_date(data$time, unit = "15 min")`? (Also not sure about the capitalization of `Time` in your data, or your data frame name... inconsistent in the question.)

Comment: sure, should I add it to the question or do you recommend other site to post it?

Comment: Add it to the question. And just make it a relevant subset, 6 rows, 2 columns is plenty.

Comment: Add it to the question. And, please tell us the date format, `mdy`, `dmy`, etc.

Comment: very similar to Gregor's answer you can also use lubridate::round_date(data$time, unit = "15 min") if you want to group in the closest 15 - min interval

Comment: I added the sample data from dput

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with your `dput`, calling it `df`, first we'll convert your factor to a `POSIXct` class, then we will `floor` it to closest 15 minutes below. (use `round` instead of `floor` if you want the closest 15 minutes in general):

```
df$time = as.POSIXct(df$time)
df$time15 = lubridate::floor_date(df$time, unit = "15 min")
df
#                  time value1              time15
# 1 2016-04-11 15:12:49      0 2016-04-11 15:00:00
# 2 2016-04-11 15:13:05      0 2016-04-11 15:00:00
# 3 2016-04-11 15:13:21      0 2016-04-11 15:00:00
# 4 2016-04-11 15:13:37      0 2016-04-11 15:00:00
# 5 2016-04-11 15:13:54      0 2016-04-11 15:00:00
# 6 2016-04-11 15:14:10      0 2016-04-11 15:00:00
# 7 2016-04-12 16:22:38      0 2016-04-12 16:15:00
```

You can then aggregate using the `time15` column as the grouper.

Comment: floor_date was exactly what I needed. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

I provide an example you can replicate with your data frame. First, I create a dummy time series (ts)  `as.POSIXct` by 5 min intervals and then group them by 15 min intervals using `dplyr`.

```
ts <- seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2017-01-01", tz = "UTC"),
                 as.POSIXct("2017-02-01", tz = "UTC"),
                 by = "5 min")
ts <- as.data.frame(ts)
library(dplyr)
ts %>%
   group_by(interval = cut(ts, breaks = "15 min")) %>%
   summarise(count= n())
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 2,977 x 2
   interval            sumvalue
   <fct>                  <int>
 1 2017-01-01 00:00:00        3
 2 2017-01-01 00:15:00        3
 3 2017-01-01 00:30:00        3
 4 2017-01-01 00:45:00        3
 5 2017-01-01 01:00:00        3
 6 2017-01-01 01:15:00        3
 7 2017-01-01 01:30:00        3
 8 2017-01-01 01:45:00        3
 9 2017-01-01 02:00:00        3
10 2017-01-01 02:15:00        3
# ... with 2,967 more rows
```